# How can I add an onBlur event to a selectizeInput

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, selectize.js

I would like to trigger an event when the user leaves a selectize-Input. However for selectizeInput it does not work and for textInput it only fires once:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectizeInput("si", label="letters", choices = letters),
  tags$script(HTML(
    '
      $("#si").on("blur", function() {
        console.log("boawigjawegaosdgi");
      })
      '
  )),
  textInput("ti", label = "ti"),
  tags$script(HTML(
    '
      $("#ti").on("blur", function() {
        console.log("boawisdgi");
      })
      '
  )),
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

What could I change so it works?

Comment: Probably because you are doing this on the UI section of your app instead of doing it on the Server part, triggered by a reactive event?

Comment: But this has nothing to do with the UI/server distinction, as the js code will be executed in the browser anyways?

Comment: It works fine for the text input.

Comment: You are right, it works, I thought that it only works once because my browser did not print it out twice but instead once and has a little "2" at the very right side of my screen in order to show that it has triggered a second time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works normally for the `textInput` For the `selectizeInput`, you have to use the `onBlur` option:

```r
  selectizeInput(
    "si", label="letters", choices = letters,
    options = list(
      onBlur = I('function() {console.log("boawigjawegaosdgi")}')
    )
  )
```